# How to use latest web3 version from metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask

Im new to web3 and Im using following code to connect my UI to web3.

```
// Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
            // Request account access if needed
            console.log("window.ethereum");
            ethereum.enable();
        } catch (error) {
            // User denied account access...
        }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        console.log("window.currentProvider");
        // Acccounts always exposed

    }
    // Non-dapp browsers...
    else {
        console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
    }

    console.log("version");
    var version = web3.version;
    console.log(version);
```

The output of console is this, which means it is using 0.20.3 version of web3. 
[image]

who is actually injecting this version? If metamask is injecting then why it is not injecting the latest version which is 1.0.0-beta.

P.S: metamask version is 6.0.1

Answer (score 2):

You can 'override' the version injected by Metamask, so that you get more cross-browser/cross-wallet compatibility.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
    web3.eth.getAccounts().then(...)
</script>
```

See for example the [bounty given by Opera](https://explorer.bounties.network/bounty/2326)

Comment: Yes, worked for me. Using Metamask 7.2.2.